# Transpose a dataframe inplace into a for loop (python-pandas)

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, transpose, in-place

I have a list of dataframes. All the dataframes have 75 columns and variable number of rows (between 18 to 1000). The column names are dates, I will use these dates to plot time series. There are ~50 dataframes in the list.
I want to tranpose all the dataframes and I want to use a for loop. I am also doing some other editions to the dataframes inside the loop (e.g., dates to datetime format)

I know that `df.T` allows to transpose a dataframe, however when I do
`for df in dfs: df = df. T`
it does not work, it does not save inplace. I am traying to find a way to do it inplace but I have not find any solution.
I also tried
`for df in dfs: df.tranpose()`
and it does not work.

Comment: `df = df.T` definitely transposes a DataFrame as a basic test will demonstrate. The problem is your loop; you are taking each DF, transposing it and then assigning that object to the name `df`. You need to directly change the elements in the List (as in the answer given below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try something like:

```
for i in range(len(dfs)):
    dfs[i] = dfs[i].T
```

This should write the transposed dataframe back into the list.

Comment: Thanks! It works. 
I still don't understand why for df in dfs: df = df. T doesn't work but for i in range(len(dfs)):  dfs[i] = dfs[i].T does

Comment: The transposition is not done in place, so the original dataframe in the dfs list is unchanged by df=df.T. Instead, the variable df now refers to the transposed dataframe. In the next iteration of the loop, df is redefined to be next dataframe in the loop, and the previously transposed version now has no way to access it. In the answer, it was written back to the list, overwriting the original dataframe.

Comment: If still in doubt about what was happening you should look further into Python names and objects. The name is not the object, it is just a label you assign to the object. This explanation might help [Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)